# Nginx: Job for nginx.service failed

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx

After installing `Apache` web server some days ago, I just installed `Nginx` web server on my Ubuntu local machine in order to setup a reverse proxy server. But when I try to start up `Nginx` server by running the command below in my terminal

```
systemctl start nginx
```

I get the error below

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I have tried to check the status of `Nginx` service by running the command below

```
 systemctl status nginx.service
```

but I get the response below

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-10-10 12:39:18 WAT; 16s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 6501 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code
  Process: 6500 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
```

I have tried to fix the issue, but I seem not to be make any headway.

I need some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is this, I already had `Apache` web server installed and actively listening on port `80` on my local machine.

`Apache` and `Nginx` are the two major open-source high-performance web servers capable of handling diverse workloads to satisfy the needs of modern web demands. However, `Apache` serves primarily as a HTTP server whereas `Nginx` is a high-performance asynchronous web server and reverse proxy server.

The inability of `Nginx` to start was because `Apache` was already listening on port 80 as its default port, which is also the default port for `Nginx`.

One **quick workaround** would be to stop `Apache` server by running the command below

```
systemctl stop apache2
systemctl status apache2
```

And then starting up `Nginx` server by running the command below

```
systemctl stop nginx
systemctl status nginx
```

However, this same issue will arise again when we try to start `Apache` server again, since they both use port `80` as their default port.

**Here's how I fixed it**

Run the command below to open the default configuration file of Nginx in Nano editor

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

When the file opens in Nano editor, scroll down and change the default server port to any port of your choice. For me, I chose to change it to port `85`

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
       listen 85 default_server;
       listen [::]:85 default_server;
```

Also, scroll down and change the virtual host port to any port of your choice. For me, I also chose to change it to port `85`

```
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
# server {
#        listen 85;
#        listen [::]:85;
```

Then exit the file by pressing on your keyboard

```
Ctrl + X
```

And then Press **Y** on your keyboard to save the changes.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**